# routerLink in angular to display the html page in a new window

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

My current application looks like this. If I click predict I want the application to open new html page and prints its contents.

[image: Screen 1]

But when I click on predict,the url gets updated to

> http://localhost:4200/predict

and the contents in the

> predict.html

gets appended to the screen 1.

[image: Screen 2]

I want to display only the contents from the predict.html file when I click predict.

Here's my app.component.html file where I have included routerLink for predict

```
 <div style="padding-top:30px;padding-left:350px;">                                
 <a routerLink = "predict" >Predict</a>                               
</div>                              
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have added the following in my app.module.ts file

```
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
         path: 'predict',
         component: PredictionComponent
      }
   ])
  ],
```

Comment: You have a predict.html file in your application folder ?

Comment: @MartinPaucot Yes I have predict.html in my app folder.

Answer (score 0):

here u just add `target="_blank"` in `anchor` tag and then check

if this won't work then you can simply add `click handler` and bind any method like  `goToPredictPage` on `anchor` instead of using `routerLink`

```
<div style="padding-top:30px;padding-left:350px;">                                
 <a (click)="goToPredictPage()" >Predict</a>                               
</div>                              
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in your ts file add manual routing which will open route page in new tab

```
goToPredictPage(){
    this.router.navigate([]).then(result => { window.open(`/predict`, '_blank'); });
}
```

here `this.router` is instance of `Router`

so add this in constructor of ts file

```
constructor(public router: Router) { }
```

Comment: when I add target="_blank" in anchor tag,it just opens the new window but displays the predict html upon the base html page. When I did click event it also opened a new window but predict.html file did not load.